# How do I summon projectiles (specifically snowballs) above mobs in a certain radius when I am holding a certain item?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am currently trying to make a repeating command block continuously check if the player is holding a specific item (in this case, a fishing rod named "Snowball Bazooka"), and if the player is holding said fishing rod, then it will summon a snowball or some other projectile above all the mobs *except for* the player in a radius of about 10 blocks.

It seemed a bit more feasible before the /execute command was changed, but now, trying to get it to somehow work in 1.14, I don't exactly see a clear way to do this (I haven't used command blocks too much, so maybe I don't know too much about them yet to understand how to make this work.)

This is what my attempt was at coming up with a solution:

```
/execute if entity @a[nbt={Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:fishing_rod",Slot:-106b,tag:{display:{Name:"\"Snowball Bazooka\""}}}]}] run execute at @e[type=!player,distance=10] run summon snowball ~ ~10 ~
```

Comment: Try replacing `if` with `at`. That should already do the trick, if there isn't another mistake that I've not spotted. Edit: Also, you probably want to use `SelectedItem:{…}` instead of `Inventory:[{…}]`, otherwise you just check if you have that item anywhere. Also, nothing got made impossible in 1.13 commands, only more things became possible or easier.

Comment: I'll give that a go. Also, it's good to know that 1.13 didn't make anything impossible, I thought some commands were removed or just merged with other commands.

Comment: Some commands were removed. `/toggledownfall` was removed, because `/weather` already did what people used it for anyway (clearing rain), `/stats` was removed, because you can now do the same and more much easier with `/execute store`, `/testfor` was removed, because it basically did nothing anyway (instead you now say "do X if condition matches" in one command, which was already recommended since 1.9), `/testforblock` and `/testforblocks` were removed for the same reason and `/blockdata` and `/entitydata` were removed in favour of `/data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is pretty simple to make it but i have no idea how to make so you need to hold an item with an specific name… this command works so you need to hold any fishing_rod with any type of name to summon arrows over near entitys

put this command in a reapet command block and have it on always active or power it manually when you want to activate the thing

execute as @p[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:fishing_rod",Count:1b}}] run execute at @p run execute at @e[distance=0..10,type=!minecraft:player,type=!minecraft:arrow,type=!minecraft:item] run summon minecraft:arrow ~ ~3 ~

then put this command in a second command block on chain, always active and conditional

kill @e[type=minecraft:arrow,nbt={inGround:1b}]

now when you holding in a fishing_rod it will summon arrows over all near mobs! enjoy